# Extract text from web with python and scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the text of each headlines of a [web news](https://www.bcb.gov.br/noticias) with a simple spider code on python using scrapy. I leave part of the html code below

```html
<div _ngcontent-c17="" class="col-md-8"><h2 _ngcontent-c17="" class="cormorant">Notícias</h2>
<ul _ngcontent-c17="" class="list-unstyled lista-noticias"><!----><!---->
<li _ngcontent-c17="" class="noticia hvr-shadow py-3 d-block"><!---->
<div _ngcontent-c17="" class="container-noticia"><div _ngcontent-c17="" class="data pr-3"><span _ngcontent-c17="" class="dia cormorant">02</span><span _ngcontent-c17="" class="mes">Abril</span><span _ngcontent-c17="" class="hora cormorant">14:25</span></div><div _ngcontent-c17="" class="texto pl-3"><div _ngcontent-c17="" class="assunto"></div><!----><a _ngcontent-c17="" bcblink="" class="d-block" href="/detalhenoticia/434/noticia">
<h4 _ngcontent-c17="" class="cormorant">CMN autoriza o BC a conceder empréstimos mediante emissão de Letra Financeira Garantida e a firmar acordo de swap com o Federal Reserve</h4>
```

Thus, I would like to extract the text in h4. For this, I have the following code in python using scrapy:

```
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class Pregunta(Item): 
    titulo = Field()
    id = Field() 

class BcbSpider(Spider): 
    name = "bcb_noticias" 
    start_urls = ['https://www.bcb.gov.br/noticias']

    def parse(self,response): 
            sel = Selector(response) 
            preguntas = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled lista-noticias"]/li') 
            
            for i, elem in enumerate(preguntas):
                item = ItemLoader(Pregunta(),elem)
                item.add_xpath('titulo','.//h4[@class="cormorant"]/text()')
                item.add_value('id',i)
                yield item.load_item()
```

There is no error when I run my code in Powershell. However it soes not **scrape** anything

I leave part of the message below

```
2020-04-06 11:21:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-04-06 11:21:25 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-04-06 11:21:25 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on (IP number)
2020-04-06 11:21:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.bcb.gov.br/noticias> (referer: None)
```

The code works in other web pages. I don't know if maybe I'm writing the xpath correctly (I've tried writing it in several forms), or there is another issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website uses dynamic rendering. You need Selenium or similar tools to scrape this.
Alternatively, you can download the JSON containing what you're looking for directly from :

```
https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/servico/sitebcb/noticias?listsite=conteudo/home-ptbr&listname=Notícias
```

And parse it with the tool you want.
[image: BCB]